# Не сохраняется позиция видимого итема в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Использую режим adjustResize, обычный RecyclerView и после него EditText, при появлении клавиатуры окно сжимается но видимые элементы в RecyclerView опускаются вниз.

[image]
[image]

Структура макета выглядит так:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Пробовал устанавливать setStackFromEnd в true, в LinearManager не помогает.
Версии библиотек: 25.3.0

Как можно избежать этой неприятной проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте слушатель `View.OnLayoutChangeListener`:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        try { // на случай если адаптер не установлен
            //Скролл к последнему элементу
            //mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
            //Скролл к последнему видимому элементу
            //mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(((LinearLayoutManager)(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())).findLastVisibleItemPosition());
            //Скролл к последнему полностью видимому элементу
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(((LinearLayoutManager)(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
});
```

При изменении `layout` Вашего `RecyclerView` (скрыть/показать клавиатуру) он будет скроллиться к последнему элементу.

Comment: При каждом открытии будет скроллится до низа, что не хорошо. Нужно скроллить последнего видимого элемента, я так думаю

Comment: Я конечно знаю про свойства `LinearLayoutManager` (`manager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` или `manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()`) :) Но думаю это стоит внести в ответ :)

Comment: @zTrap, обновил